# Delphi 7 IDE Stack Overflow Error

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-7, stack-overflow

Could anyone tell me, why I keep getting the following errors?

**Background:**

The project has 320 Embedded Forms.

The projects search path has 205 folders, at a length of just over 11,000 chars.

If I remark out just 1 of the embedded form units, then it compiles without an error.

**IMAGE #1 - From Delphi IDE**

[image]

**IMAGE #2 - From DCC32.EXE**

[image]

Here is the unit I use for my embedded forms

```
unit EmbeddedForm;

interface

{$INCLUDE '..\INCLUDE\BUILD.INC'}

uses
  Windows, Controls, Messages, Forms;

type
  TEmbeddedForm = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure StopFlicker(var theMessage: TWMEraseBkgnd); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure InitializeForm(); virtual; abstract;
    procedure FinalizeForm(); virtual; abstract;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}
procedure TEmbeddedForm.StopFlicker(var theMessage: TWMEraseBkgnd);
begin
  theMessage.Result := 1;
end;

procedure TEmbeddedForm.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
const
  ParamStyle = WS_VISIBLE or WS_POPUP or WS_OVERLAPPED or WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  Params.ExStyle := (Params.ExStyle and (not WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE)
    and (not WS_EX_STATICEDGE) and (not WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME) and (not WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE));
  Params.Style := (Params.Style and (not WS_CAPTION) and (not DS_MODALFRAME)
    and (not WS_DLGFRAME) and (not WS_THICKFRAME));
  Params.Style := Params.Style and not ParamStyle;
end;

procedure TEmbeddedForm.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  CanClose := False;
end;

procedure TEmbeddedForm.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caNone;
end;

end.
```

Comment: can you suppress the problem by removing any form?

Comment: Yes, It doesn't care what form I remove.

Comment: you could try using a PE editor to increase stack size of IDE or dcc32. But make backups first! Editbin should do this.

Comment: @eyeClaxton - a wild shot but you could try removing unused units from your uses clause. CnPack has a wizard to do this automatically for you.

Comment: @Lieven - No unused units to remove I always use Icarus.

Comment: Are you autocreating many/all of these forms? Or are you creating and freeing them as needed?

Comment: @Ken Why would runtime autocreation influence a compile time Stack Overflow?

Comment: @David: It wouldn't. Autocreation of the forms in the IDE would, if the desktop is being saved so that it's restored when the IDE is opened.

Comment: @Ken I don't see that, and in any case what about the dcc32 failure?

Comment: @David: I don't know that the DCC32 failure is the same thing, and regardless commenting out a single form might fix one, but not the other. I think there's something else going on here, and was trying to get an idea what it might be. (A stack overflow in the IDE compiler could be totally different than the error shown by DCC32, as they aren't the same compiler (or error messages).)

Comment: @Ken - Creating and freeing them as needed?

Comment: @David - Your comment of "try using a PE editor to increase stack size of IDE and dcc32" worked just fine.  I increased the dcc32.exe to (/STACK:268435456) and the delphi32.exe to (/STACK: 134217728).  If you could post your comment as an answer I will accept.

Comment: done. Out of curiosity, did editbin do the job or did you use something else.

Comment: Editbin.exe from Visual Studio 2010 v10.00.30319.01

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using a PE editor to increase the stack size of IDE or dcc32. But make backups first! Editbin should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change these values:

Project->Options->Linker->Memory sizes

Min stack size as hex value

Max stack size as hex value